# I am trying to use chainlink using remix and i followed the chainlink docs

Tags: solidity, remix, oracles, external-api, chainlink

[image]

I am facing this issue,What to do now?

My Code

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.7;
import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/master/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
contract PriceConsumerV3 {
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;
   
    constructor() public {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
    }
  
    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int) {
        (
            uint80 roundID, 
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add your code instead of the image to the code? It's not helpful for others to find this unless you paste both the text of the error and your code.

Comment: I have added can you have a look at it

Comment: It needs to be pasted as text instead of an image

Comment: just now i have edited

Comment: can you look it now

Comment: chainlink lib seems to be quite busted. :/

Answer (score 3):

The location of the interface changed in GitHub. The contract is now located here: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol

You can find the updated code for the price consumer here: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/documentation/blob/main/_includes/samples/PriceFeeds/PriceConsumerV3.sol Currently it uses Solidity `^0.8.7`.

Comment: not helpful, your link is broken.

Comment: Helped me find the latest version to import. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your import URL isn't correct. Set it to this:

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
```

Also you may need to change your pragma solidity line so the version matches what you're importing (ie v6 versions of the CL contracts). ie:

pragma solidity ^0.6.7;

Comment: this gives me the error "not found" in remix